# How is OpenGL fragment shading performed?

Tags: opengl, colors, shader

I have a 3D object I've created in Maya (and exported to OBJ and MTL files) and I've created a model viewer app in OGL to view it. If my assumptions are correct (and you know what they say about assumptions...) then because I haven't specified my own GLSL shader, OGL should be using the FFP to determine the fragment colour for each pixel? Is this correct?

In my understanding, the FFP must be implement some sort of default shader because it is able to display specular highlights and reflections etc. Can someone give me some information on this and perhaps tell me how this shading is done?

I understand the material definitions are used to set the properties of the materials of the objects, but I'm unsure of how to the final effects of the lights interacting with material display in the OGL window, without manually specifying a shader (hence my belief that there is some default shader).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case of 3rd generation and later GPUs all your assumptions are correct, indeed. As long as no custom shader is specified the driver provides the GPU with a default shader mimicking the FFP.

The default shader usually implements a Phong Lighting model, with the exact details depending on the set parameters of texture environment and such.

For older GPU generations the fixed function pipeline is hardwired.

Comment: Thank you! I have been searching for days for this answer! I can't understand why this information is so hard to come by! Is this default shader included with the OpenGL library you use (JOGL or LWJGL) or does it reside somewhere else? I'm also guessing to emulate a Lambert material, you just turn off all specular settings in the GL context?

Comment: This default shader normally comes with the driver. OpenGL, contrary to what the naming suggests, is not a library per se (of course you link against some library). It's an API to the driver, and as such the driver is responsible for implementing the default, too. Emulating a Lambert material happens by setting the GL_SPECULAR component of the material to 0.

Comment: On a side note, this information is quite clearly stated in the OpenGL specification.

Comment: Perhaps you could point me in the direction of this information? From reading the specification, it appears quite vague to me. "When the current fragment shader program object includes a fragment shader,
its fragment shader is considered active, and is used to process fragments. If the
fragment shader program object has no fragment shader, or no fragment shader
program object is currently in use, the results of fragment shader execution are
undeﬁned." It doesn't seem to mention anything about default values there. Perhaps I'm looking in the wrong place? Thanks again for the answer though!

Comment: OpenGL separates shaders into two pieces: The shader objects defining the pieces of a full shader program, and the program itself itself. Think the shaders like .obj files of the whole shader program. And just like with compilation of an executable if an object is missig the whole executable is undefined. You may also be referring to OpenGL 4, which indeed requires you to supply sufficient shaders. However OpenGL-1.2 and OpenGL-2 are still mostly used. Coercing to a default shader is defined somewhere between Versions 2.1 and 3.1 IIRC.